# Вывести массив json

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Есть примерно такая структура файла `one.json`

```
{
  "img": "1.jpg",
  "name": "имя 1",
  "time": "10-20 минут"

},
{
  "img": "2.jpg",
  "name": "имя 2",
  "time": "20-30 минут"
},
{ "img": "3.jpg",
  "name": "имя 3",
  "time": "15-25 минут"
  }
```

Вот код

```
$.getJSON('one.json', function(data,key) {

$.each(data, function(key, data) {

    $('#json').html("<p>"+key+" "+data.name+data.img+data.time+"</p>")
});


});
```

Comment: и? вопрос-то в чем?

Comment: Не работает код

Comment: смотрите консоль браузера, наверняка там ошибка вроде: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

Comment: В консоли нет ошибок

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка в файле `one.json`. В нем содержится не валидный json и если подписаться на ошибки то можно увидеть следующую ошибку

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token , at Object.parse (native) at jQuery.parseJSON (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.js:7961:14) at ajaxConvert

Чтобы исправить ее нужно изменить json так, чтобы в нем был массив

```
[{
  "img": "1.jpg",
  "name": "имя 1",
  "time": "10-20 минут"

},
{
  "img": "2.jpg",
  "name": "имя 2",
  "time": "20-30 минут"
},
{ "img": "3.jpg",
  "name": "имя 3",
  "time": "15-25 минут"
}]
```

---

Еще одно дополнение: вызывая в цикле `$('#json').html(...)` значение каждый раз перезаписывается, поэтому в конце цикла в данном элементе будет только последняя запись.

Comment: Крутяк. Спасибо за разъяснения!